# How do I get rid of these subselects?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have this query:

```
select distinct pdi.height, pdi.width, pj.jobnum
        , (select count(barcode) from productiondoorinformation 
            inner join view_productionjobs on view_productionjobs.ctr=productiondoorinformation.productionjobsctr
                where view_productionjobs.jobnum=pj.jobnum 
                    and productiondoorinformation.height=pdi.height 
                    and productiondoorinformation.width=pdi.width
                    and productiondoorinformation.alternaterating='PARTICLE') as particleqty
        , (select count(barcode) from productiondoorinformation 
            inner join view_productionjobs on view_productionjobs.ctr=productiondoorinformation.productionjobsctr
                where view_productionjobs.jobnum=pj.jobnum 
                    and productiondoorinformation.height=pdi.height 
                    and productiondoorinformation.width=pdi.width
                    and productiondoorinformation.alternaterating<>'PARTICLE') as laminatedqty

    from productiondoorinformation pdi inner join view_productionjobs pj on pj.ctr=pdi.productionjobsctr
                where pj.jobnum='' + @Jobnum + ''
```

There has to be a better way to be a better way to do this. I hate the subselects but am not savy enough to re-write it without them. There are two different quantities that the subselects are counting that you'll notice when you see the where clauses for each.

This query takes nine seconds to execute. That's too long. Any other query I've written against these tables returns immediately. Any suggestions? I've tried group by, etc., but can only get it to work one way or the other (particle or <> particle), but not both.

The returned data should look like:

```
height | width | jobnum | particleqty | laminatedqty 
79      49       t1000    10           5
78      49       t1000    1            3
79      47       t1000    15           0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are in the right track. You should be able to use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select pdi.height, pdi.width, pj.jobnum,
        SUM(CASE pdi.alternaterating WHEN 'PARTICLE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) particleqty,
        SUM(CASE pdi.alternaterating WHEN 'PARTICLE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) laminatedqty
from productiondoorinformation pdi 
     inner join view_productionjobs pj on pj.ctr=pdi.productionjobsctr
     where pj.jobnum='' + @Jobnum + ''
group by pdi.height, pdi.width, pj.jobnum
```

BTW, not sure you need those single (`''`) quotes around @Jobnum...

Comment: I'm going to try this again, and I hope it works, but it didn't early today. It kept summing everything into the laminatedqty. I probably just had something in the wrong place. Anywho, I'll give it a go.

Comment: This will work correctly iff `productiondoorinformation.alternaterating` is not null.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I checked my old query too that was written this way and I was using the wrong dang field in the case statement. I should have known something wasn't right when it kept using the else of the laminatedqty case statement. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick throw-off - why not write the inner query as simple table with

```
CASE WHEN alternaterating = 'PARTICLE' THEN 1 ELSE 0
```

then query against that table?